# React App fetch data using Node Fetch

Tags: node.js, reactjs, fetch

I am using the Create-React-App starter app to play around with react.  I want to test getting data with node fetch, but it does not seem to work.  I am able to get it to work with axios.

I get an error to the effect that: Warning in ./~/encoding/lib/iconv-loader.js
Critical dependencies:
9:12-34 the request of dependency is an expression 
@ ./~/encoding/lib/iconv-loader.js 9:12-34

it seems to be an error in webpack:///./~/react-scripts/~/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js?

I also get an error that says: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT and it seem like the fetch is appending the port to the url when sending the request: http://codepen.io:3000/jobs.json

Code:

```
import React from 'react'
import NodeFetch from 'node-fetch' 

class NodeFetchData extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      jobs: []
    };
  }


  componentDidMount() {

    NodeFetch('http://codepen.io/jobs.json')
    .then(res => {
      this.setState({ jobs:res.data.jobs });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {this.state.jobs.map(job =>
            <li key={job.hashid}>{job.company_name}</li>
          )}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default NodeFetchData;
```

Comment: My guess is you're running afoul of the [same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). By default, most browsers will not allow JS code on a page access content from a different origin.